# In R have dataframe and needs to be corrected for data issues by subtracting columns

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I am in need of some assistance. I have created a dataframe that looks like this

```
e<- tail(finaltable2);
e;
      Dead carried Dead1 Dead2 carried1 Dead3 Dead4 carried2 Dead5 Dead6 carried3
21215    0       0     0     0        0     0     0        0     0     0        0
21247    0       0     0     0        0     0     0        0     0     0        0
21216    0       0     0     0        0     0     0        0     0     0        0
21237    0       0     0     0        0     0     0        0     0     0        0
21218    0       0     0     0        0     0     1        1     1     1        0
21227    0       0     0     0        0     0     0        0     0     0        0
```

My dataframe will consist of several columns (uncompleted at this time), but will have 250 rows.
My goal is to count the number of dead per row until it reaches 16. My problem is this, in row 21218 I have counted the dead 3 times. What I need to do is anytime this happens have a line of code that sees this and corrects this. I am thinking this might take several if and else statements. Can anyone help me design that may work?

my output would look like this if anyone could help:

```
e;
      Dead carried Dead1 Dead2 carried1 Dead3 Dead4 carried2 Dead5 Dead6 carried3
21215    0       0     0     0        0     0     0        0     0     0        0
21247    0       0     0     0        0     0     0        0     0     0        0
21216    0       0     0     0        0     0     0        0     0     0        0
21237    0       0     0     0        0     0     0        0     0     0        0
21218    0       0     0     0        0     0     1        1     0     0        0
21227    0       0     0     0        0     0     0        0     0     0        0
```

Comment: If you really want others to help, I would suggest a small reproducible example and a much clearer description of your conditions.

Comment: @ Ananda I am still new to programming, but what do you mean description of your conditions? Sorry for the lame question

Comment: it's not a lame question... It's just that I've read it a couple of times and I'm still not sure *what* the question is. By conditions I mean, what is the rule that you followed to decide the "Dead5" and other columns should be changed to "0" from "1" in row 21218? What is the relationship between that and the fact that you want to "count the dead per row until it reaches 16"? Again, it would be most helpful if you tried to write a *small* scaled down example that is easy for someone to copy and paste into their R session....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a manual way I came up with, with some input from another post.

```
indices <- (t$carried2 == t$Dead5) & (t$carried2 == t$Dead6)
t$Dead5[indices] <- 0
t$Dead6[indices] <- 0

indices <- (t$Dead5 == t$Dead6) & (t$carried3 ==0 )
t$Dead6[indices] <- 0

indices <- (t$carried1 == t$Dead3) & (t$carried1 == t$Dead4)
t$Dead5[indices] <- 0
t$Dead6[indices] <- 0

indices <- (t$Dead3 == t$Dead5) & (t$carried2 ==0 )
 t$Dead5[indices] <- 0

indices <- (t$carried == t$Dead1) & (t$carried == t$Dead2)
t$Dead2[indices] <- 0
t$Dead3[indices] <- 0
```